# Dot derivative of vector that includes a hat misaligns

Tags: amsmath

I have a vector defined as `\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \hat{x}\end{bmatrix}` and it displays as expected, however if i try to add a dot derivative it gets misaligned.

minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\dot{
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \hat{x}\end{bmatrix}}
$$
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: Misaligned vector]

Comment: Unrelated never use `$$...$$` as this is not LaTeX syntax and does not follow LaTeX configuration. Use `\[ ... \]` or similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

amsmath is working hard to enable a dot accent over a hat accent.

You can reset things inside `\dot` so it "forgets" it is in a nested accent construct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\mathaccentV@@\mathaccentV
\def\resetaccents{%
\macc@depth=\z@
\let\mathaccentV\mathaccentV@@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[\dot{\hat{x}}\]

\[
\dot{\resetaccents
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \hat{x}\end{bmatrix}}
\]
\end{document}
```